# how to calculate percentage of time over 24 hours with given time hh:mm:ss?

Tags: javascript, php

I am doing a web application,
I am trying to solve problem regarding time to percentage,
I want to get the percentage of the start time from the beginning of time of the day.

For example the start time is `08:30:00`
the total time for a day is `24:00:00`

How I get the time percentage start_time/total_time ?

as for this case should be around 33%, I cannot figure out how to calculate the minutes, and seconds.

I am doing this using php and javascript. and I want to solve it using either both of them. Maybe both?

Here is my js code:

```
var start_time = parseFloat(time_begin)/24*100;
alert (start_time);
```

Comment: user minutes instead of hours and time to calculate percentage?

Comment: What timezone? Local, UTC? How do you define when the day started?

Comment: and what kind of percentage, difference between 00:00 and start time?

Comment: time start is 00:00:00 ... I am calculating for current day only. I am trying to display the percentage value in a time bar, to show what is the time allocate for 24 hours in a day

here is my concept, although i know there is plugins out there, but is it possible to do this?

Link image : http://i.minus.com/jbkQFz5JSlmzVo.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$date = '08:53:34';
$parts = explode(':', $date);
$secs = $parts[0] * 3600 + $parts[1] * 60 + $parts[2];

// day has 86 400 seconds
echo $secs / 864 . '%'; // return 37.05% (you can round it)

?>
```

Here is PHP solution, you wrote you are using php&JS, you added both tags.
If you want to use JS solution, it´ll be similar.

Answer (score 2):

The javascript solution will use the [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) class, open up your debugger on the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K4x4b/) to see the percentage change every second.

```
  setInterval(function () {
     var secondsInADay = 24 * 60 * 60;
     var now = new Date();
     var hours = now.getHours() * 60 * 60;
     var minutes = now.getMinutes() * 60;
     var seconds = now.getSeconds();
     var totalSeconds = hours + minutes + seconds;
     var percentSeconds = 100 * totalSeconds/secondsInADay;
     console.log(totalSeconds, percentSeconds);
  }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you can use this formula:

```
$time_begin = '08:00:00';
$start_time = round(((strtotime($time_begin)-strtotime('00:00:00'))/(24*60*60))*100);
echo $start_time.'%';
```

You can give a little more precision in the rounding function.

```
$time_begin = '08:00:00';
$start_time = round(((strtotime($time_begin)-strtotime('00:00:00'))/(24*60*60))*100,2);
echo $start_time.'%';
```

JS can be done as:

```
var time_begin = '08:00:00';       
var a = time_begin.split(':');
var seconds = (+a[0]) * 60 * 60 + (+a[1]) * 60 + (+a[2]);
var start_time = Math.round((seconds/(24*60*60))*100);
```

And for a greater precision

```
var start_time = Math.round((seconds/(24*60*60))*10000)/100;
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP: I like Dan Sherwin's best, though I haven't tested it

JS: My own (tested)

```
var now = new Date(...);
var startOfDay = new Date(now.getTime());
startOfDay.setHours(0,0,0,0);
var percent = (now.getTime()-startOfDay.getTime()) / (1000*60*60*24)
```

Edit: Given your requirements, it doesn't sound like this information is needed server-side. In that case, even though this is a cheap operation, I would suggest you conserve server resources and have this performed client-side. This also makes it easier to update the bar without reloading the page, because this would otherwise require very expensive AJAX calls. The one caveat to this is if you want the time bar to function for users without JavaScript enabled, you have to go server-side.

Comment: Since it's JavaScript, I believe we can all ignore the fact that I forgot a semicolon on the last line, lol

Comment: Ok, I note that hahaha :)

Comment: Can I know how to transfer variable of the start time, let say $startTime from the php into this function?

Comment: Well, how Dan did it, $startTime is based on a max of 100, whereas in my method, it's based on a max of 1. So, dividing his result by 100 should get my result

Comment: You can set hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds in one go using `startOfDay.setHours(0,0,0,0)`. See [*Date.prototype.setHours*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.34) .